# Logs for Flash Player 13 debug version

Tags: debugging, flash, macromedia

I was looking for flashlogs.txt for Flash Player 13 debug version but I could not find it. I already set TraceOutputFileEnable=1 on mm.cfg and place it on the proper location according to [this](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7fc9.html). But I still cannot find the hard-coded flashlog.txt that should be placed in the location as stated in [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WSda78ed3a750d6b8f-4867184d1239f9d0558-8000.html). This is my system information according [here](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player.html)

Your Flash Version 13.0.0.206 (debug version)

Your browser name Internet Explorer

Your Operating System (OS) Windows (Windows 7)

Comment: honestly i never was able to find it. so i always developed in firefox with [flashbug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/flashbug/) plugin.

Comment: thanks but i need to debug it in IE9

Comment: found it!  After creating the folder Logs on my C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Macromedia\Flash Player and restarted my pc. a flashlog.txt was created!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it!
After creating the folder Logs on my C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Macromedia\Flash Player and restarted my pc. a flashlog.txt was created!